# Including php script inside javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript, php

i have included a confirm box in my PHP page which works fine the following is the code

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('Acc No :   \nCANDIDATE NAME :   \n\nPLEASE CONFIRM ')" >hi</a>
```

now i want to display value returned by PHP after Acc NO and CANDIDATE NAME i have written a code which is not working  the code is below

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('AIN NO :<?=fetchresullt['acc_no']; ?>   \nCANDIDATE NAME : <?=fetchresullt['acc_candidatename']; ?>   \n\nPLEASE CONFIRM ')" >hi</a>
```

please help me out

Comment: can you please try like this <?php echo $fetchresullt['acc_no']; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('AIN NO : "<?php echo fetchresullt['acc_no']; ?>"   \nCANDIDATE NAME : "<?php echo fetchresullt['acc_candidatename']; ?>"   \n\nPLEASE CONFIRM ')" >hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `fetchresullt['acc_no']` is spelt correctly? Doesn't it need to be a variable? ie:

```
<?=$fetchresult['acc_no']?>
```

Also make sure you are not including it in a .js file, but make it inline JS code in a .php file.